# Stirlings approximation for $\Gamma(x+\alpha)$, when $\alpha$ is very small but $(x+\alpha)$ is not necessarily small.

Tags: gamma-function

I was wondering, if we can approximate  $\Gamma(x+\alpha)$, when $\alpha \to 0$ but $(x+\alpha)$ is not necessarily small using stirling's approximation or any other way. For this case is it possible to get a lower and upper bound?

I was hoping for a similar result , I saw in wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function),when  $x \to \infty $,

$$\Gamma(x+\alpha) = \Gamma(x)x^\alpha$$

I have tried $\Gamma(x+\alpha) \approx \Gamma(x)$, but the results are not great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using a tangent for the function $x!^{1/x}$ Or a chord you have a upper lower bound is it what you want?

Comment: I want a an approximation for $\Gamma (x+\alpha)$ with some bounds so that I know for sure how good or bad the approximation is.